# Django HttResponse has no attr status_code, but docs have :)

Tags: python, django

I'm using default django httpresponse, like this:

```py
return HttpResponse("Validation Error", status_code=400)
```

And i got exception like "HttpResponse has no attribute **status_code**". But in the docs we have info about this attr ([docs link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpResponse.status_code))

If we look at source code, we can see:

```py
class HttpResponse(HttpResponseBase):
    ...
    def __init__(self, content=b'', *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        # Content is a bytestring. See the `content` property methods.
        self.content = content
...
```

Not explict usage of status_code, let's look parent's **init**:

```py
class HttpResponseBase:

    def __init__(self, content_type=None, status=None, reason=None, charset=None, headers=None):
...
        if status is not None:
            try:
                self.status_code = int(status)
            except (ValueError, TypeError):
                raise TypeError('HTTP status code must be an integer.')

            if not 100 <= self.status_code <= 599:
                raise ValueError('HTTP status code must be an integer from 100 to 599.')
        self._reason_phrase = reason
```

And here in params we can see **status**.

If we back to my example, correct version of this looks:

```py
return HttpResponse("Validation Error", status=400)
```

And my question is: "Is there place in docs where was talk about **status** of HttpResponse and if not, how i can make issue or bring this info to django-developers?"

The way I see it, it's not obvious enough.

Comment: talk about status of HttpResponse https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/http/views/#returning-errors

Answer (score 0):

the `status_code` is an attribute of HttpResponse
it means if you want to know what is the response status you can print your HttpResponse object status_code like this

```py
resp = HttpResponse()
print(resp.status_code)
```

and in the document in this [section](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/request-response/#id4) they talk about methods and arguments

for example [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpResponse.status_code:%7E:text=status%20is%20the%20HTTP%20status%20code%20for%20the%20response.%20You%20can%20use%20Python%E2%80%99s%20http.HTTPStatus%20for%20meaningful%20aliases%2C%20such%20as%20HTTPStatus.NO_CONTENT.) they talk about status argument of HttpResponse